# Access Point Poor Performance

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I'm not getting the performance I'm expecting with my WiFi setup. Both the speed seems lower than it should be and I'm often getting dropped connection. Turning WiFi on/off on the mobile device usually fixes the connection problem, but that's not why I invested in access points.

Here's my setup:

[image]

I can clarify in the comments as needed.

I have good speed and stability on the hardware connections. The WiFi Wireless connections are slow, and drop frequently.

Is there some settings on the Router that are making the connection poor?
Is transferring the signal between the Archer C5 Wifi Router and the Access Points causing problems?

Any suggestions on a better physical topology?
I have roughly 8 hardware connections (excluding the access points) and probably have around 20 WiFi connections.

With 1GB Fiber, and my hardware connections frequently testing over 600Mbs, bandwidth to the internet is not an issue.

Interesting the Nice Trace app can't find anything from mobile devices. The TP Link Tether App doesn't see any of the TP Link devices.

Comment: You have 4 AP's in an environment... This issue is likely due to improper wifi implementation (channel separation, SSID names, band steering, etc), improper coverage area, or external influences (anything from other WiFi devices, ballast in fluorescent lights, or anything else generating RF). Just going on the given information, I would suggest getting a WiFi spectrum analysis done by a reputable and experienced WiFi vendor or purchasing something like a Wi-Spy DBx from MetaGeek (just an example, there are lots of products out there) and perform the operation yourself.

Comment: You made a mistake in using AP technology rather than Mesh that uses a superior technology. Your house is probably overly covered and devices are not always connecting to the right AP. I don't know about the TL-WA801N, but try to set a different SSID for each one (if possible) to minimize interference.

Comment: @dvdhns Hi. What do you mean for _poor_ performance? TL-WA801N seems to be a 300Mbps Wireless Access Point... Even with all the computers turned off, with 20 wireless connections equally shared among Archer and TL-WA801N units, you have an average of 5 clients connected at the same time to the same access point... 300/5=60 Mbps (on average) that means  60/8 =~7 MByte per second. Even the Archer C5, arrives up to 867Mbps at 5GHz (but up to 300Mbps at 2.4GHz). And we are not considering the bandwidth shared with the wired computers... TL use some _save power_ settings... Still few? Let we know.

Comment: @dvdhns: Have you abandoned your question?

Comment: @harrymc nope, still looking for solutions, just havent been able to respond

Comment: I do not want to have separate SSID's for each access point. That was the prior setup with some wifi extenders, and everyone hated having to switch wifis based on where they were.

Comment: It could be that the devices are not switching from one AP to another AP because there's too much overlap. I think it would help if I could determine which AP I was connected to. I bought Nice Trace to do that, but it doesn't work at all. Will look more into Wi-spy DBx.